# Javascript — Add transform : translate to existent style

Tags: javascript, css, transform

In a project, I use Javascript to give custom `translateY` transforms to several elements.

The issue I'm facing right now is about adding a `translateY(value)` to multiple elements when some of those elements already have a `translateX(value)` in their CSS style.

So of course, `el.style.transform = translateY(value)` actually *erase* `transform: translateX(value);` CSS property.
Is there a way to **add/merge** a `translateY` to an existing `translateX` in plain Javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've actually maybe found a solution, didn't thought about that way — get CSS properties in javascript and translate "matrix" properties into values > https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If this style is presented as object:

```
Object.assign(el.style.transform,translateY(value));
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

It will add to existing object new styles.

If it is string property - use concatenation of string.

More information : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robert, it's not really what I was looking for but it could be helpful in another case! I've found a kinda perfect solution which I'll post here for those who facing the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally found a solution using `getComputedStyle()` function.
The following code is looking for any `translateY` value, if so it apply a different transform style on the targeted element.

```
let l = window.getComputedStyle(el, null),
    t = l.getPropertyValue('transform')

    // If t return other than "none"
    // Split content into several value
    // The fourth one is the translateX value

    if(t != 'none') {
        let v = t.split('(')[1],
            w = v.split(')')[0],
            x = v.split(',')

        el.style.transform = 'translate(' + x[4] + 'px, -' + d / m + '%)'
    } else {
        el.style.transform = 'translate('+ 0 + 'px, -' + d / m + '%)'                   
    }
```